# Segmentation fault in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

I am new to C and am trying to figure out pointers. I tried this simple(according to me) code and keep getting a segmentation fault in GCC

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c[50] = "abc";
    char h[50];

    char *ptr;
    printf("abc");
    ptr = c;

    printf("Address stored in ptr: %p" , ptr);

    printf("Value of ptr: %s" , *ptr);
}
```

I read up on segfaults and found that they occur when i try to reference memory that does not belong to me. Where am I doing this in this code? Thanks!

Comment: Turn your warning level up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this statement

```
printf("Value of ptr: %s" , *ptr);
```

to either

```
printf("Value of ptr: %c" , *ptr);
```

or

```
printf("Value of ptr: %s" , ptr);
```

depending on what you want to see. Or use them both that to see the difference.:)

Answer (score 1):

`printf("Value of ptr: %s" , *ptr);` tells the computer to interpret the value stored at the address pointed to by `ptr` as the address of a string. In most cases that would be the address of an unmapped memory region (`0x636261` on little-endian machines, e.g. x86 / x64) and therefore the segmentation fault.

Since the `%s` format specifier expets the address of a string, it is not necessary to dereference the pointer:

```c
printf("Value of ptr: %s" , ptr);
```